# Highcharts inactive state must be applied to all items except for hovered item

Tags: javascript, html, css, charts, highcharts

With reference to the following
jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/2f17L4at/

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {

chart: {
    type: 'column'
},

title: {
    text: 'Disabled inactive state'
},

xAxis: {
    categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr']
},

plotOptions: {
    series: {
        states: {
            inactive: {
                enabled: true
            }
        }
    }
},

series: [{
    data: [1, 3, 2, 4]
}, {
    data: [5, 3, 4, 2]
}]
});
```

When I hover over series1 in jan, the series1 for other months are also highlighted. I only want series for the hovered month to be highlighted and everything else should be in inactive state. Can anyone help me with how to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop through points from the active series and set their state to inactive:

```
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            point: {
                events: {
                    mouseOver: function() {
                        const point = this;

                        point.series.points.forEach(p => {
                            if (p !== point) {
                                p.setState('inactive');
                            }
                        });
                    },
                    mouseOut: function() {
                        const point = this;

                        point.series.points.forEach(p => {
                            if (p !== point) {
                                p.setState('normal');
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            },
            ...
        }
    }
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/fsdw21em/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Point#setState